# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I wanted to specify the format of the date because it's in European format(Or else the dates will not be in order after I make it as index column). I did exactly from the tutorial as follow:
[image]

But after I execute

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date,format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I get this error

```
df = pd.read_csv("F:\Python\Jupyter notes\AUDCAD1h.csv")
df.columns = [['date', 'open','high','low','close','volume']]

df.head()
Out[66]: 
                               date     open     high      low    close volume
0  01.01.2015 00:00:00.000 GMT-0500  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821    0.0
1  01.01.2015 01:00:00.000 GMT-0500  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821    0.0
2  01.01.2015 02:00:00.000 GMT-0500  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821    0.0
3  01.01.2015 03:00:00.000 GMT-0500  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821    0.0
4  01.01.2015 04:00:00.000 GMT-0500  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821    0.0

df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.date,format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-67-29b50fd32986>", line 1, in <module>
    df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.date,format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

  File "C:\Users\AM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 376, in to_datetime
    result = _assemble_from_unit_mappings(arg, errors=errors)

  File "C:\Users\AM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 446, in _assemble_from_unit_mappings
    unit = {k: f(k) for k in arg.keys()}

  File "C:\Users\AM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 446, in <dictcomp>
    unit = {k: f(k) for k in arg.keys()}

  File "C:\Users\AM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 441, in f
    if value.lower() in _unit_map:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

How come I got the error but the one I followed didn't? I copied the code exactly. What's wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: why not use the parameter for european dates? `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: After I specify the date as index column. The order of the dates are all messed up.

Comment: can you post a print of what you mean by messed up?

Comment: DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 12:00:00', '2015-01-01 13:00:00', '2015-01-01 14:00:00', '2015-01-01 15:00:00', '2015-01-01 16:00:00', '2015-01-01 17:00:00', '2015-01-01 18:00:00', '2015-01-31 19:00:00', '2015-01-31 20:00:00', '2015-01-31 21:00:00', ... '2017-01-12 11:00:00'] As you see, the date jumps from 2015-01-01 18:00 to 2015-01-31 19:00. But there is 2015-01-01 19:00 in the dataset in European format

Comment: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have double brackets in the columns name.

Also why not let pandas work for you? Example,

EDIT: since you don't want the GMT part to be taken into account, I removed it with a list comprehension

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("date_t.csv")

print(df)
df.columns = ['date', 'open','high','low','close','volume']

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime([x[:-9] for x in df['date'].squeeze().tolist()], dayfirst=True)

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

print(df)
```

EDIT 2: explanation of the line
`[x[:-9] for x in df['date'].squeeze().tolist()]`

> `df['date'].squeeze()` -> squeeze dataframe column in a series
>
> `df['date'].squeeze().tolist()` -> turn in into a list
>
> `[x[:-9] for x in df['date'].squeeze().tolist()]` -> for each date in the list keep only the elements until the 9th counting from the end, meaning remove the GMT part

From your subset data, this is what I get. Pandas is smart enough to understand the GMT-0500 and convert the dates taking this into account.

```
                              1        2        3        4        5      6
0  01.01.2015 00:00:00.000 GMT-0500  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0
1  01.01.2015 01:00:00.000 GMT-0500  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0
2  01.01.2015 02:00:00.000 GMT-0500  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0
3  01.01.2015 03:00:00.000 GMT-0500  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0
4  01.01.2015 04:00:00.000 GMT-0500  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0
                        open     high      low    close  volume
date                                                           
2015-01-01 00:00:00  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821     0.0
2015-01-01 01:00:00  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821     0.0
2015-01-01 02:00:00  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821     0.0
2015-01-01 03:00:00  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821     0.0
2015-01-01 04:00:00  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821  0.94821     0.0
```

Comment: Use the code I provided above, it gets the dates right

Comment: Even if I use your code, I get the AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower' error, which is the same issue I originally had.

Comment: whats your pandas version?

Comment: My pandas version is 0.21

Comment: I'm sorry, I have noticed now the double square brackets, it's just one to be correct. In the columns name.

Comment: I am sorry, the error is gone after I used single bracket. But the time are all wrong. For ex. 01.01.2015 17:00:00.000 GMT-0500's data will become 01.01.2015 12:00:00.000. (It's new york time in my dataset, I don't know if pandas converted to something else, which is NOT GMT by the way) So confusing...

Comment: @yomoko I've updated my answer to take into account those -5 hours

Comment: I don't really understand what your new edited line does. But it solved the problem somehow, thanks. PS. From the tutorial I followed, he used double brackets also, and it worked for him. But it doesn't work for me. I am very confused....

Comment: I have added an explanation

Comment: I had same error but with a filed that has strings as 20180101. I was able to use your solution to use to_datetime but I still do not know what caused the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I am also replicating this algorithm and had the same error till I realized it was an issue with how I downloaded the data. Select GMT when downloading from Dukasopy instead of local then you can use his original code

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

df = pd.read_csv('GBPUSD.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)