# Understand to_datetime AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, pandas

I have inherited some very messy legacy code that calls Google Analytics API and saves some metrics into a pandas dataframe.

There is a `date` column which is a string and I want to convert to a date. I would normally use pd.to_datetime, like this `final['date'] = pd.to_datetime(final['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')` but it gives me this error:

`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'`

This is description of the dataframe:

`print(final.info())`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 37047 entries, 0 to 37046
Data columns (total 5 columns):
(date,)               37047 non-null object
(landingPagePath,)    37047 non-null object
(sessions,)           37047 non-null object
(bounces,)            37047 non-null object
(market,)             37047 non-null object
dtypes: object(5)
memory usage: 1.4+ MB
None
```

I have found a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698720/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-lower) and the solution works if I do

`final['date'] = pd.to_datetime([x for x in final['date'].squeeze().tolist()], dayfirst=True)`.

However I still do not understand what caused the issue in the first place. I guess that the column is somehow inconsistent, but I do not know how to identify which row is the culprit. What's the best way to find out?

Comment: Oh man, you've inherited some bad code indeed. Somehow you have tuples instead of scalars in the df. Can we see `print(df.head())` or at least an imitation of what that looks like if the data is sensitive?

Comment: I suspect that it may be an issue with how the data is being pulled from SQL and put into the dataframe

Comment: thanks for your reply. All the rows displayed by `print(df['date'].head())` appear with %Y%m%d format. The data was pulled from Google Analytics API.

Answer (score 1):

as in my very similar case, please check `type(final['date'])`.
`pd.to_datetime()` works mostly with `pd.Series`.

This could even explain why `squeeze()` works. It converts `DataFrame` to `Series`.