# Need a more efficient datetime conversion for/into pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Good morning Stackoverflow.

I am trying to find a better way to suck in a CSV file and parse the datetime. Unfortunately my data is coming in as a '%j:%H:%M:%S.%f', such as 234:17:33:00.000206700. I have the year sitting in another field from my header I skip over, so this was my method of converting prior to setting as index, since I have date rollovers to account for.  It works, but is slower than I would like and is not intuitive.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(data_file,skiprows=np.arange(0,meta_lines),header=[0,1,2])

dataframe['Temp'] = meta['Date'].split('-')[2] + ' '  # splitting off the year from 08-22-2019
dataframe['Temp'] = dataframe[['Temp','AbsoluteTime']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x),axis=1)
dataframe['AbsoluteTime'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['Temp'],format='%Y %j:%H:%M:%S.%f')
del dataframe['Temp']

dataframe.set_index('AbsoluteTime', inplace=True)
```

Originally I wanted to have pd.to_datetime parse without the %Y, resulting in the year 1900 and using time delta to add X years, however when I started down that path, I came across this error.

```
dataframe['AbsoluteTime']
Out[8]: 
       DDD:HH:MM:SS.sssssssss
                Absolute Time
0      234:17:33:00.000206700
1      234:17:33:00.011264914
2      234:17:33:00.015721314
...
```

```
pd.to_datetime(dateframe['AbsoluteTime'],format='%j:%H:%M:%S.%f')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-6dfc074c2dc4>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.to_datetime(dateframe['AbsoluteTime'],format='%j:%H:%M:%S.%f')

NameError: name 'dateframe' is not defined


pd.to_datetime(dataframe['AbsoluteTime'],format='%j:%H:%M:%S.%f')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-bfbf7ee22833>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.to_datetime(dataframe['AbsoluteTime'],format='%j:%H:%M:%S.%f')

  File "C:\Users\fkatzenb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 512, in to_datetime
    result = _assemble_from_unit_mappings(arg, errors=errors)

  File "C:\Users\fkatzenb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 582, in _assemble_from_unit_mappings
    unit = {k: f(k) for k in arg.keys()}

  File "C:\Users\fkatzenb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 582, in <dictcomp>
    unit = {k: f(k) for k in arg.keys()}

  File "C:\Users\fkatzenb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 577, in f
    if value.lower() in _unit_map:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

What gives?  My problem isnt from having double brackets [[]] like other threads with this error addresses. If I do this as a test, I see...

```
pd.to_datetime(['234:17:33:00.000206700'],format='%j:%H:%M:%S.%f')
Out[6]: DatetimeIndex(['1900-08-22 17:33:00.000206700'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I was then just going to add a timedelta to that to shift the year to the current year.

My only thought is I have is it having to do with my multiple column header (see my from_csv command).  Thoughts?  Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698720/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-lower)

Comment: Nope.  I had previously read that topic and the entry point into the problem was different and the solution wasn't one I could leverage.

Comment: On the `read_csv`, could you use the attribute `parse_dates` and give it a list of lists to parse both year and the rest of the date together?  Not sure if that would work though.